How to pass arguments to extendscript from osascript
I'm trying to run a extendscript script(on after effects) using osascript (from my backend spring boot application)
The below is the command that im executing,
String command = String.format(
  "osascript -l JavaScript -e 
      \"ae = Application('Adobe After Effects 2024'); 
        ae.activate(); 
        ae.doscriptfile('%s');\"", filePath );


How can I pass arguments to my extendscript? I saw people using scriptArgs but I don't know how can I use that.. I want something similar to process.argv of node
